# sub-process termination in case of a hang(Win)

Tags: windows, process, termination

I have a Process called "Agent" it spawns a new process called "Connect". This "Connect" process loads the service dll's. The "Connect" process start a sub process(cmd.exe), I would like to know if for some reasons the loaded dll's cause a hang or a crash, how to ensure that "cmd.exe" is terminated.

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740256/process-management-in-net/3740297#3740297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CreateProcess to spawn the new process. The involves setting up and passing in a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure: which will contain a handle to the new process (hProcess) if the call to CreateProcess works.

You can now do a WaitForSingleObject on this process handle to see when the process finishes. WaitForSingleObject allows you to timeout if the object does not trigger (i.e. process does not terminate), and hence take action (TerminateProcess I presume).